# How to push back value to fusion vector during runtime?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

How to push back value to fusion vector during runtime?

```
  typedef boost::fusion::vector<A*, B*, C*> vec_t;

  vec_t vec_;

  vec_.push_back(new A());
```

Comment: The sequence operations that are done on a `fusion::vector` are all compile-time-only. Once the type has been computed at compile time, a `fusion::vector` becomes no more than a tuple. If you want a run-time mutable vector then you should use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence operations that are done on a `fusion::vector` are all compile-time-only. Once the type has been computed at compile time, a `fusion::vector` becomes no more than a tuple.

If you want a run-time mutable vector then you should use `std::vector`.